# Filter Objects of Array of Objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a *Objects of an array of objects* as given below. I am trying to filter out each object within the array where is **quantity is greater than 0** and drop it in a new variable. So via `lodash` I tried to use `_.filter` within `_.(myArr).forEach`. But this always returns an empty array. The console.log within `_.filter` shows `quantity` as it is but it doesn't return any value based on the condition. Am I using it in a proper way here or is there any other way I can use this to filter out?

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "aid": "1",
    "desc": "Desc 1",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "aid": "2",
    "desc": "Desc 2",
    "name": "Name 2",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "aid": "3",
    "desc": "Desc 3",
    "name": "Name 3",
    "quantity": 0
  }],
  [{
    "aid": "4",
    "desc": "Desc 4",
    "name": "Name 4",
    "quantity": 0
  }, {
    "aid": "5",
    "desc": "Desc 5",
    "name": "Name 5",
    "quantity": 1
  }],
  [{
    "aid": "6",
    "desc": "Desc 6",
    "name": "Name 6",
    "quantity": 0
  }, {
    "aid": "7",
    "desc": "Desc 7",
    "name": "Name 7",
    "quantity": 0
  }]
];

var filtered;
_(data).forEach((d) => {
  filtered = _.filter(d, (o) => {
    return o.quantity > 0;
  });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `filtered` in each iteration, so its value will represent only what happened in the last iteration of the `forEach` loop.

You should instead accumulate the individual results into an array, for instance with `push` and the spread syntax:

```
var filtered = [];
```

... and in the loop:

```
    filtered.push(..._.filter(d, (o) => o.quantity > 0);
```

Note that you can do this in vanilla JavaScript, using array methods like `reduce` and `filter`:

```js
var data = [ [{ "aid": "1", "desc": "Desc 1", "name": "Name 1", "quantity": 1 }, { "aid": "2", "desc": "Desc 2", "name": "Name 2", "quantity": 1 }, { "aid": "3", "desc": "Desc 3", "name": "Name 3", "quantity": 0 }], [{ "aid": "4", "desc": "Desc 4", "name": "Name 4", "quantity": 0 }, { "aid": "5", "desc": "Desc 5", "name": "Name 5", "quantity": 1 }], [{ "aid": "6", "desc": "Desc 6", "name": "Name 6", "quantity": 0 }, { "aid": "7", "desc": "Desc 7", "name": "Name 7", "quantity": 0}]];

var filtered = data.reduce( 
    (filtered, d) => filtered.concat(d.filter( o => o.quantity > 0 )),
    []
);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome..  Thank you so much for the detailed response.. :)

Comment: Which of the above approaches you suggest as the best to adapt? :)

Comment: Since JavaScript ES5 and certainly ES6 there is less reason to use a library as lodash, but if you need it for other purposes which cannot be written that well in ES6, then of course you can use it throughout.

Comment: Well yeah, I am using `lodash` in most of the areas of the project, so I would be going with the same.. Thank you so much once again.. :)

Answer (score 2):

using native js:

```
let filtered = data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e)).filter(x => x.quantity > 0);
```

Comment: There is more data than only in `data[0]`.

Comment: `data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))`, `[...data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))]`, `[...data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))].reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), [])` -> There three will produce the same output, isn't it?

Why don't we directly write `data.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e))
.filter(x => x.quantity > 0);`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RaR you are absolutely right. I've got lost mixing approaches. I'm very glad you'd notice it, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively you can use `reduce`

```
var output = data.reduce( 
    ( acc, c ) => acc.concat( c.filter( 
           s => s.quantity > 0 ) )  //filter out quantities > 0
    ,[]); //initialize accumulator to []
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  [{
    "aid": "1",
    "desc": "Desc 1",
    "name": "Name 1",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "aid": "2",
    "desc": "Desc 2",
    "name": "Name 2",
    "quantity": 1
  }, {
    "aid": "3",
    "desc": "Desc 3",
    "name": "Name 3",
    "quantity": 0
  }],
  [{
    "aid": "4",
    "desc": "Desc 4",
    "name": "Name 4",
    "quantity": 0
  }, {
    "aid": "5",
    "desc": "Desc 5",
    "name": "Name 5",
    "quantity": 1
  }],
  [{
    "aid": "6",
    "desc": "Desc 6",
    "name": "Name 6",
    "quantity": 0
  }, {
    "aid": "7",
    "desc": "Desc 7",
    "name": "Name 7",
    "quantity": 0
  }]
];
var output = data.reduce( ( acc, c ) => acc.concat( c.filter( s => s.quantity > 0 ) )  ,[]); 
console.log(output);
```

Comment: That errors out.. `c.filter` is not a function.. :(

Comment: Ohh, let me share a demo with you. `C` is an array so it must have a filter method.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Please check the updates, I have attached a demo now.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I would like to go with the accepted answer. But nonetheless, this will be useful somewhere in future.. :)